# Who killed this character at the Battle of Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

At the Battle of Hogwarts, this character was killed:

> Then Neville nearly walked into him. He was only half of a pair that was carrying a body in from the grounds. Harry glanced down and felt another dull blow to his stomach: Colin Creevey, though underage, must have sneaked back just as Malfoy, Crabbe, and Goyle had done. He was tiny in death.

But we don't know where or when he died, or how.  Is there any evidence as to who killed him?

Comment: You poor soul. It was a war. Not every life lost in a war has a heroic story behind it. Some deaths are just lost meaninglessly.

Comment: It was JKR, the heartless witch.

Comment: @b_jonas I don't care about a heroic story, I just want to know who killed him.  Is that too much to ask?

Comment: @CHEESE what evidence are you willing to accept if the answer is "we don't know"?

Comment: Could've been anyone, except poor Voldy: " Haven't you noticed how none of the spells you put on them are binding? You can't torture them. You can't touch them. You don't learn from your mistakes, Riddle, do you?”

Comment: @CHEESE - It's not too much to ask, but it is, alas, too much to answer.

Comment: @Neeshka That was after Harry's sacrifice in the Forbidden Forest, and Colin died before that (Harry sees them carrying his corpse on his way there). Voldemort's spells would have been fully effective at the time Colin died. Still unlikely that it was Voldemort himself (did he even do any fighting until after Harry's "death"?) though.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Voldemort was never master of the Elder Wand, so his spells done with it were never fully effective. That's why he killed Snape: he realized that something was wrong, and thought that's how he could fix it.

Comment: @Martha Not exactly true. Voldemort himself says that he did exceptional magic with it; the issue was that it wasn't any more exceptional than his magic before obtaining the Elder Wand. There is no evidence whatsoever (barring a quote from JKR that I'm not aware of) to suggest that Voldemort's spells weren't fully effective before he tried to kill Harry in the Forbidden Forest. Unless you want to suggest that Voldemort wasn't capable of killing Colin Creevey without the power boost from the Elder Wand...

Comment: @AnthonyGrist so he was killed right away. That's depressing.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: I think we're just operating under slightly different definitions of "fully effective". You're right, of course, that Voldy was fully capable of killing Colin even with a recalcitrant wand, but that we have no evidence that he did so.

Comment: https://www.moviefone.com/2016/10/19/colin-creevey-actor-j-k-rowling-was-trigger-happy-harry-potter/ - The actor is in agreement with me on this one. She just killed him for a laff.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**We don't know.** The specific circumstances of his death aren't detailed in the books, films or any other [media](https://twitter.com/search?q=colin%20from%3Ajk_rowling&src=typd&lang=en-gb). All we know is that he died during the Battle of Hogwarts, likely as a result of Death Eater enemy action.

> They moved Voldemort’s body and laid it in a chamber off the Hall,
>   away from the bodies of Fred, Tonks, Lupin, Colin Creevey and **fifty
>   others who had died fighting him**

There's also the possibility that he died due to friendly fire (a [distinct possibility](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91232/in-the-harry-potter-universe-can-a-spell-deflect-or-redirect-to-hit-an-unintende/91235#91235)), a battlefield accident or an unrelated health condition but from a narrative perspective those seem quite unlikely.

Comment: Harry had the strongest motivation to silence the Creevey brothers forever in the books. Just saying. ..

Comment: @Neeshka - Harry strikes me as the sort of person who sincerely hates the paparazzi.

Comment: It's a good answer, but hard to accept.  If something more conclusive pops up, I'll choose it, until then, you have my favor.

Answer (score 1):

I am not saying this answer is accurate in any way. It seems to have no substantial quotes as to where the info came from, but taken from:

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Muggles%27_Guide_to_Harry_Potter/Characters/Colin_Creevey

> Colin, seen in the Great Hall, is told to evacuate the school with the other underage wizards, but apparently somehow makes his way back to the school. He is killed by Death Eaters in the final Battle of Hogwarts; in the quiet time after Harry has seen Snape killed, Harry sees Oliver Wood and Neville Longbottom bringing Colin's body in from the grounds.

Comment: This all seems correct, but does it say who killed him?

Comment: short of saying "death eaters" no. Note the quote does say "He is killed by Death Eaters in the final Battle of Hogwarts". I think thats as close to who as we get.

Comment: The reason I specifically believe what I shared is noteworthy is whereas it may not specifically name a name, it does imply the previous answer couldn't be correct, specifically "There's also the possibility that he died due to friendly fire (a distinct possibility), a battlefield accident or an unrelated health condition but from a narrative perspective those seem quite unlikely.". If it was by death eaters, all those possibilities are out the window

Comment: @Bruce Sure, but there's absolutely nothing to back up the claim that it *was* Death Eaters. It's the most likely answer, but there's no evidence to prove it, so there's still a possibility that one of Valorum's suggestions or something else entirely (e.g. a giant or some other magical creature on Voldemort's side) was the cause of his death.

Comment: Well yes thats why I started by stating I am not saying this answer accurate, simply the closest thing I could find to an answer other than "not known"

Comment: There's no indication that this fan-written entry is accurate. It adds to canon (stating that he definitively died of death-eater action) without confirming where that info came from.